# a problem of upper limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $[-\infty,\infty]$. For $k=1,2,3,\ldots$, let
$$b_k=\sup\{a_k,a_{k+1},\ldots\}$$ and $$\beta=\inf\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots\}.$$
Then we say $\beta$ is the upper limit of $\{a_n\}$, named by $\beta=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$.
From the above definition, we can easily get
$$b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq\cdots,$$
hence $b_k\to\beta$ when $k\to\infty$. And also, there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_{n_i}\to\beta$ when $i\to\infty$, and $\beta$ is the biggest number having this property. 
How can I construct such $\{a_{n_i}\}$ explicitly and prove the maximality of $\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: when finite, $\inf S$ (resp. $\sup S$) is always a cluster point of the set $S$, meaning that every $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\inf S$ (resp. $\sup S$) will contain an element of $S$.  You can use this to construct your $\{a_{n_i}\}$ (provided $\beta$ is finite - if it's infinite, you should be able to see what to do).

Then, to show that $\beta$ is maximal, try a proof by contrapositive or contradiction.

Comment: I'm also puzzled over your answer.Can I select the subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ from the definition of subsequence $\{b_{k_i}\}$?If $b_{k_i}>b_{k_i+1}$,we get $a_{n_i}$ between $$a_{k_i},a_{k_{i+1}},\cdots,a_{k_i+1}.$$ Thus we get a decreasing sequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ which converges to $\beta$.

Comment: Since $b_k$ is a nonincreasing sequence, it will in fact converge to $\beta$.  Then, for each $b_k$, you can select a subsequence of $a_k$ converging to it (since the $b_k$'s are supremums).  Then, from those subsequences, filter out your final subsequence $a_{k_j}$.  It helps to draw a picture.